# Duplicate column names in the result are not supported in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to select some columns in BQ and getting a complaint about duplicate IDs:

```
Duplicate column names in the result are not supported. Found duplicate(s): id
```

The query I'm using is:

```
SELECT
  billing_account_id,service.id,service.description,sku.id
FROM `billing-management-edab.billing_dataset.gcp_billing_export_v1_blah_blah_blah`
```

Why are service.id and sku.id considered duplicates? And how can I get around that in my query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give aliases to the two `id` columns:

```
SELECT
    billing_account_id,
    service.id AS service_id,
    service.description,
    sku.id AS sku_id
FROM `billing-management-edab.billing_dataset.gcp_billing_export_v1_blah_blah_blah`
```

Actually, you may have left out part of your query, in particular the other table(s) which themselves were aliased as `service` and `sku`.  But in any case, giving each of the two `id` columns in your select clause as a distinct alias should resolve your error.